# Полезные фичи в PHPSTORM

Tags: php, phpstorm

Кто знает о полезных фичах в phpstorm, например как просканировать коды на ошибки и форматирование.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
help->productivity guide
```

Все или почти фичи представлены со статистикой и подробным описанием как использовать.

Answer (score 5):

> как просканировать коды на ошибки и форматирование.

делается автоматом

> полезные фичи

- PHPMD и PHPCS в inspections. Придется установить из локально, и, возможно, написать собственные xml'ки, зато потом эта штука будет автоматом подсвечивать слишком засоренные участки кода
- Run configurations. На эту кнопку стоит вывести "обнуление приложения", чтобы без проблем начинать с чистого листа, туда же можно вывести команды с тестовым функционалом, чтобы их без проблем отдебажить. Можно создать команду `validate`, которая будет прогонять тесты и общую валидацию проекта, и запускать перед коммитом.
- Refactor. Тут и в целый комментарий не влезет, но это просто охрененная штука.
- File watchers. Это наикрутейшая штука, которая, правда, редко нужна. В основном это автокомпиляция всяких less при изменении, но за пару минут можно прикрутить (!) автотесты на класс - просто выдеруть путь к классу в проекте, подставить Test.php и нужную команду, например, phpunit - и при любом сохранении автоматом будет вылетать предупреждение о неверном выполнении (т.е., если тесты не прошли). Я до сих пор у себя это не развернул, но это должно быть просто божественно в условиях неторопливой разработки.
- Key promoter plugin. Быстро научит пользоваться хоткеями, хотя в некоторых местах без мыши не обойтись и он начинает подбешивать.
- Поддержка нескольких репозиториев внутри проекта. У меня прямо сейчас с этим некоторые проблемы, но это безумно круто, черт побери.
- Самый обычный дебаг с xDebug. При нормально идущей разработке всегда стоит пользоваться им вместо вардампов и прочего отстоя.
- Интеграция с TeamCity и Jenkins. Еще не пробовал, но так или иначе проект надо верифицировать перед коммитом, и если есть возможность прогнать тестовый билд - это вообще невероятно.
- При установке зависимостей можно пометить папку vendor как excluded, и кинуть ее же в include path в секции PHP настроек проекта. В результате все классы будут доступны внутри проекта, но их не затронет при рефакторинге.

**Обновление**

Я попробую попозже написать подробный пост, но если вкратце:

- Можно изменить имя класса сразу во всех упоминаниях в проекте. Спасает от ада с ошибками "класс не найден"
- Аналогично - переименование перемнной внутри функции. Shift + F6, десять секунд затраченного времени - и никакой фрустрации от того, что где-то остались криво названные переменные.
- Как только становится ясно, что кода в методе/функции слишком много - нужный выделяется, нажимается refactor - extract - method, и выбранный код отправляется в новый метод класса.
- Автогенерация геттеров/сеттеров

Comment: Для чего refactor?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, я попробую попозже написать подробный пост, но если вкратце:

* Можно изменить имя класса сразу во всех упоминаниях в проекте. Спасает от ада с ошибками "класс не найден"
* Аналогично - переименование перемнной внутри функции. Shift + F6, десять секунд затраченного времени - и никакой фрустрации от того, что где-то остались криво названные переменные.
* Как только становится ясно, что кода в методе/функции слишком много - нужный выделяется, нажимается refactor - extract - method, и выбранный код отправляется в новый метод класса.
* Автогенерация геттеров/сеттеров

Comment: Благодарю - многое для меня в новинку

Comment: Спасибо. Если еще что-то вспомните - дописывайте. Сам с недавнего времени перешел на PhpStorm, набор возможностей впечатляет.

Answer (score 0):

Одна из полезнейших фич PHPStorm - это простота кастомизации, вплоть до убирания ненужных пунктов главного и выпадающих меню. Возможно, Вам будет интересно почерпнуть некоторые идеи [отсюда](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-U8pTS_xw-w), ведь look and feel играет не последнее значение, но мало кто об этом задумывается.